# Conditional rowsum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a correlation matrix calculated from `df.corr()`. I am attempting to get a rowsum for each row of this matrix, with the positive and negative values separately. A row of the correlation matrix looks something like this:

```
    A    B     C
A  1.00 -0.044 -0.8
```

Expected output:

```
Variable PositiveCorr NegativeCorr
A        1.00         -0.844
```

How can I achieve this in Pandas?

Comment: Can you add some example with expected ouput?

Comment: Edited to reflect the matrix a bit more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) with `sum`:

```
df['PositiveCorr'] = df.clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1)
df['NegativeCorr'] = df.clip(upper=0).sum(axis=1)

df1 = df[['PositiveCorr','NegativeCorr']].rename_axis('Variable').reset_index()
```

To avoid appending new columns to original `DataFrame`, use:

```
df1 = (df.index
         .to_frame(name='Variable')
         .assign(PositiveCorr=df.clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1),
                 NegativeCorr= df.clip(upper=0).sum(axis=1)))
print (df1)
  Variable  PositiveCorr  NegativeCorr
A        A           1.0        -0.844
```